# Create temporary table from view

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3.

Suppose I have a view `view_intermediate`. I would like to create a temporary table from this view. In other words, turn the result of the view into a temporary table.

How should the SQL statement look like to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite supports `CREATE TABLE AS..SELECT`, so assuming you want the data in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
SELECT *
FROM view_intermediate;
```

If you want a table to be created from the view, but don't want the data, you can add a false condition.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
SELECT *
FROM view_intermediate
WHERE 1=2;
```